# Groovysh launch interactive command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using groovysh as an alternative to bash. There is one thing I cannot get working. Let suppose I want do some operations and then launch vim. Doing that in bash is as simple as just writing `vim file.txt`. When I'm running a bash command with groovysh I usually do `"command args".execute().text` or similar. But it just executes the program and waits for output not giving any input to the command

Is there a way to give the control to an interactive program like vim(or ssh, top, etc) when using groovysh

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for `execute`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()) point to [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

I tried this in groovysh

```
pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("vim")
pb.inheritIO()
p = pb.start()
```

But I ended up with an extremely messy blend of groovysh and vim both attempting to be controlled by the same input.

Not sure how to get the vim process to run in the foreground.